# MySQL and c#: How do i subtract a value from two tables?

Tags: c#, mysql

im trying to subtract price from my current money.

This is my query. ill update the item to be owned, where Name = what i have selected in a listbox. and then i will update my money to money - price. but it send back a error, something with FROM.

```
"UPDATE Items SET Owned = '1' WHERE Name = @RecipeId " + 
"UPDATE [User] SET Money = Money WHERE IsActive ='1' - Price FROM Items WHERE Owned ='1'
```

If i Remove `"WHERE IsActive ='1'"` from my code, it will substract but it will do that on all user's, that why i want to add `"WHERE IsActive ='1'"` to my query

Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

```
UPDATE u SET Money = u.Money - i.Price FROM [User] u, Items i
  WHERE i.Owned='1' AND i.IsActive = '1'
```

Not sure whether `IsActive` is from `Items` table. And what is the link between `User` and `Item`? Do you have only one record in `User`?

PS: It is better to use numeric value for `Owned` flag, not char `'1'`. Define it as `tinyint` and compare/assign `Owned=1`.

Comment: IsActive is from my user table, price is from items. but ehm what is u.money and i.price how does that work?

Comment: @MortenSyhlerJensen `u.` and `i.` are alias of `User` / `Items` tables. It is for shorter syntax. Instead of `Items.Owned` you define `i` alias and then use it `i.Owned`. I like 1-2 char aliases but they can be longer as well.

Comment: Arghh, okay thanks for the quick reply :) and thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

the second one should be:

```
UPDATE [User] SET Money = Money  - Price FROM Items WHERE Owned ='1' and IsActive ='1'
```